# RF-AutoIT: Cant upload files in Chrome

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I am trying to create a common exe for 3 browser based file upload using below code.

- IE (Choose File to Upload),
- Chrome (Open),
- Firefox (File Upload)

This is working for IE but not for Chrome and FireFox. There is no error but its not showing given file along with path.

I will be using this .exe in my Robot Framework script.

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

SelectWindowBasedOnTitle()

Func SelectWindowBasedOnTitle()

    $winList = WinList()
    $wTitle = CheckWindows($winList)

   IF $wTitle == "Choose File to Upload" Then
            IE()
   ElseIf $wTitle == "Open" Then
            Chrome()
   Else
            FireFox()
   EndIf
EndFunc


Func CheckWindows($aArray)

    For $i = 1 To Ubound($aArray) - 1
        If WinActive($aArray[$i][1]) Then $wTitle= $aArray[$i][0] ;MsgBox(0, "Window Check", $aArray[$i][0] & " is active.")
    Next
    Return $wTitle
EndFunc


Func Example()
    $wText = WinGetText("[ACTIVE]")
EndFunc

Func IE()
    ControlFocus("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1")
    ControlSetText("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
    ControlClick("Choose File to Upload","","Button1")
EndFunc

Func Chrome()
    ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
    ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
    ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
EndFunc

Func FireFox()
    ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
    ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
    ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
EndFunc
```

This way i am using in my Robot script. Could you please help me understand is there a way to automate

```
${FileInfo}     ${CURDIR}\\Xpaths.txt
    ${AutoIT}     ${CURDIR}\\BrowserBasedWindowSelection.exe
    Run Process   ${AutoIT}   ${FileInfo}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error? If you get no errors, what happens? Does it upload the wrong file? Upload the right file to the wrong location? Corrupt the file that is uploaded? ...?

Comment: There is no error as such. but in chrome/FF its not selecting/entering path. I mean its not uploading any file.  NOT SURE its same code for IE but for Chrome/FF its not doing anything.

Comment: Any reason why AutoIT is used to perform a browser based upload? It seems to me that this can be solved using pure Selenium/Webdriver approach.

Comment: hi @A.Kootstra, Selenium/WebDriver approach is not working with IE and FF. For chome it works fine.  To Avoid multiple Keywords i am using AUTOIT